# Headset mic is not shown

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I know this is a very known problem but I did not find any answer that solves my problem
I have Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) newly installed on my lenovo-ideapad-330 machine.
My Headset have one jack for input & output.
Also tried some solutions which I found on several websites

First: editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and I did not complete this step because I Cannot find ALC236 in this link https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html

Second: installing pavucontrol
inside this program the headset is shown as unplugged
[pavucontrol screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAdDE.png)
also in the configuration tab the profile is "Analog Stereo Duplex"

when I connect the headset at the first place it shows nothing at the input device field [sound settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlgO7.png)

**Need Help!**

**NOTE:** I have windows installed on the same machine and there is no problems with the headset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting two lines in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

then reboot

well, hope someone can explain why that solved the issue & what do these two lines mean.